# List versus Library for contract storage

Tags: list, document-library

What are the pros and cons of using a list versus library for storing contracts? Each contract has several columns such as contract number, contract type, date, status... about 15 in total.

I also have the actual contracts as pdf's, these will just be stored not edited.

Being very new to sharepoint, I don't know if I should store this structure in a list or library.

Answer (score 0):

list = the primary "row" is data, and there may or may not be a document to attach.

library = the primary "row" is a document, and there may or may not be additional data fields to enter.

Also, while lists store attachments, the attachments aren't version controlled, and the user experience is not so great.